# Create a Subversion branch from an already modified trunk working copy

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch, branching-and-merging, subversion-edge

There's a situation that I create a working copy from Subversion's trunk.

I then go changing things. Onoly ffter some changes have been made, I decide I wanna stage the work and do multiple commits over it.

But I don't want this work to be inside trunk just yet. I wanna create a branch for it, do some commits, then merge it into branch.

But that working copy was created over trunk, and changes have already happened and are urging to be commited.

How can I create a new branch and turn that working copy's changes to it?

I use CollabNet and VisualSVN and Tortoise.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your working copy folder, then right click.. from there you will see:

**TortoiseSVN > Branch/Tag**

After you click the branch/tag , there is option there named "**Working copy**" under "*Create copy in the repository from:*"

with that you can create a new branch of your working copy including the changes you made.

Regards.

Comment: I don't like this option, as it creates a copy AND a change at the same time. The log is harder to follow that way, in my opinion it is better to copy first then commit the changes.

Comment: @Ben but in Hikari's case , he doesn't want to commit yet, that's why i advise him to create a branch so that he can manipulate the newly created ranch with his changes., then if he want to go back to the original.. he can now use the switch.

Comment: Yes creating a branch is good. But I disagree with creating a branch from the working copy, as that will automatically commit the changes to the branch. Better to create the branch from a repository version (the default option) and switch to it, *then* commit the changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the branch normally as if you had not made any changes, then "switch" to the new branch (TortoiseSVN has a nice checkbox in the branch dialog to do this automatically), all your local (uncommitted) changes will come along for the ride and you can commit them whenever you want on the new branch.